# My code for Hackerrank challenge Service Lane doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a challenge in www.hackerrank.com named Service Lane at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/service-lane. I have checked my code very carefully but it's still wrong in some cases. Here is my code: (in Javascript)

```
function main() {
    var n_temp = readLine().split(' '), i, s;
    width = readLine().split(' ');
    for(var a0 = 0; a0 < n_temp[1]; a0++){
        var i_temp = readLine().split(' '); s = 3;
        for (i=i_temp[0];i<=i_temp[1];i++) {s = Math.min(s,width[i]); if (s == 1) break;}
        console.log(s);
    }
}
```

The challenge has a list of numbers (stored in *width*, their values are between 1 and 3) and some test cases (include a starting number: *i_temp[0]* and an ending number: *i_temp[1.]*, both of which are inclusive). The mission is to get the smallest number in the elements from *i_temp[0]* to *i_temp[1.]* of *width*.
Here is one of the cases that don't work:
[Input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1331/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1465479684&Signature=0P32CbVtdNkxdlXDSmEIly%2Fxh6k%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)
[Output](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1331/output02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1465479667&Signature=aKkSUoKQSiXezuGSo9MCdDJPSEw%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)
What is wrong with the code? It works successfully in some cases. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: What are the cases in which it doesn't work? What error are you getting in console?

Comment: I don't know. The site just shows me the input and the output. It doesn't show me the expected output. There is no error.

Comment: `What's wrong with this code?` We don't know it's purpose, that's wrong.

Comment: What is it supposed to do exactly? what are you inputting? what are you expecting of output?...

Comment: ok, I just run your code on your link, and site tell me code is ok. Are you select `Javascript` before run?

Comment: You can read the mission in the link above. The elements of width have the value of 1, 2 or 3. Check from width[i_temp[0]] to width[i_temp[1]], find the smallest value of the elements.

Comment: @vp_arth I chose Javascript.

Comment: "What is wrong with this code" questions are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse string to Integer.Otherwise comparison may fail on some input.I have tested below and got succeeded.

```
var n_temp = readLine().split(' '), i, s;
width = readLine().split(' ');
for(var a0 = 0; a0 < n_temp[1]; a0++){
    var i_temp = readLine().split(' '); s = 3;
    for (i=parseInt(i_temp[0]);i<=parseInt(i_temp[1]);i++) {s = Math.min(s,width[i]); if (s == 1) break;}
    console.log(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function main() {
    var N, n, path, i, j, it, res;
    [N, n] = readLine().split(' ').map(Number);
    var path = readLine().split(' ').map(Number);
    for (var it = 0; it < n; it++) {
      [i, j] = readLine().split(' ').map(Number);
      res = Math.min.apply(null, path.slice(i, j+1));
      console.log(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code worked as I changed the line 6-7 to `console.log(Math.min.apply(null, width.slice(i_temp[0], ++i_temp[1]));` (no s, i needed). Mine may be wrong because of this line. What is the different between the line above and the line 6-7 in my code?